# AWS Cognito User Pool - "Value null at 'userName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null" - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I've been working with UserPools on AWS Mobile Hub. I have managed to make login with providers like Facebook and G+. However, when trying to login with AWS UserPools I can't manage to do so. I can Register successfully and connect to the UserPool perfectly (It recognizes wrong passwords 7 nonexistent users). When I login with the method shown below, I get the error:

> "1 validation error detected: Value null at 'userName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null"

I don't really know whats happening as the username and password are actually right! (Even if hardcoded). Here you can see the code I'm using to login:

```
    let pool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool(forKey: "UserPool")
    let user: AWSCognitoIdentityUser = pool.getUser(textFieldEmail.text!)


    user.getSession(textFieldEmail.text!, password: textFieldPassword.text!, validationData:nil, scopes: nil).continueWithBlock { (task:AWSTask) -> AnyObject? in

            if task.error == nil {
                print("Got: \(task.result)")
            } else {
                print("Error while logging in: \(task.error?.userInfo["__type"]) with message: \(task.error?.userInfo["message"])")
            }

            return nil
        }
```

I would really appreciate some help! I've tried to add info on the validation data. Things like:

```
let userName:AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType = AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType()
    userName.name = "userName"
    iserName.value = textFieldEmail.text
```

But again, not working.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found the answer to this? I'm currently facing the same issue here. It's frustrating.

Comment: No!! :( @tyegah123

Comment: I solved this by upgrading the SDK to the latest version. (2.4.9) :D

Answer (score 1):

That message means the input you're giving for the username is null, I'd dive deeper into how you're populating that field.

As far as validation data goes, don't worry about that. It isn't supposed to go in there, just the username/password fields.

Comment: I'll try @Jeff! Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

I believe the key should be USERNAME and not userName similar to below:

```
    let userName:AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType = AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType()
          userName.name = "USERNAME"
          userName.value = textFieldEmail.text
```

Also, userName.value is misspelled to userName.value You shouldn't be getting this error anymore as we have updated the error messages to reflect the actual keys that should be used (USERNAME in this case).